# How to apply Antiforgery on ASP.NET Core with Angular 7 forms?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken, asp-net-core-spa-services

It seems a simple and straightforward question but when you have a fully separated UI (Angular) from your API (.NET Core), how can you still apply antiforgery token validation in your API? Is it that you have to make a GET request to some API endpoint to somehow get the cookie/token back or is it there any other way to achieve this?

I'm not even sure whether what I'm proposing is even good practice but I don't really know how to get the cookie value without making the call if the user navigates straight to the page where the form is.

I have also tried to get the actual token back on a previous page and used the standard token/cookie names however subsequent httpclient (angular) calls don't seem to be including the token and according to the docs it should be picked up automatically?

Comment: Ever get a solution?

Comment: Not really. Kept reading a I think the problem I’m trying to solve is more related to CORS and request throttling than Anti Forgery

Comment: I have been trying this https://www.domstamand.com/secure-your-angularasp-net-core-application-with-anti-forgery-token/

Comment: But it works but doesn't work when authorization is enabled